# How to use DatabaseConfiguration from apache commons with a properties file configures datasource name

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons, apache-commons-config

I am moving our config properties from a properties file to a database using apache commons DatabaseConfiguration.  Works fine.  However, it obviously needs  database definition, and I want to load that with a jndi datasource name that is itself a property.  So I want to keep a property file with that property and one or two others, that would load first and get used by the database configuration.

I have tried about a million permutations and I can't seem to get it to work.  If I hardcode the jndi name in the spring config, it works, but whether I include both in the same property configurator or separate ones, whether I use the order property or not...nothing seems to work.

Here's one of my iterations that didn't work:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/esp.properties" />
    <property name="order" value="10" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer2" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="order" value="20" />
    <property name="properties" ref="dbConfigFactory" />
</bean>
```

dbConfigFactory there is the factory that includes the databaseconfiguration bean.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: any solution, even am looking?